# How long should an LED Backlit LCD monitor last?, and why should I choose it as an instance of a CRT monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, desktop-computer, lcd, crt

How long should my new LED Backlit LCD monitor last?, and what will happen once it reaches it's lifespan?
And how long should I change my monitor? (1 year? , 6 years? ,etc...)?
And thank you guys!

Comment: I have never had and led monitor fail yet, replace it when it fails.

Comment: There's no specification for lifetime of a monitor; I have ten year old monitors still working well. When it fails, take it to a repair ship and ask then to replace the capacitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CRT Monitors are susceptible to noticeable burn in whereas LED backlit monitors are far more resistant to such an effect. They are easily good for 5 to 7 years. I have a seven year old ThinkPad with LED monitor and it is a decent as new.

Any other LED monitor we have at clients is no older than the above and all of them are still good.

Answer (score 2):

How long is a piece of string?

All electronics last until the day they fail.

It's a bell curve around MTTF [mean time to failure].
At one end is the device that's already dead on arrival. At the other is the machine that runs on for decades.
You will never know until the day arrives.